# Creating Critical Path Algorithm using Kotlin

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, kotlin

So I've been trying to find a way to implement a critical path using Kotlin and I can't find anything online about it. Are there any examples which create a critical path using Kotlin and/or Scala.
Currently, each task has a unique ID, time it takes to complete tasks (Hours) and has either 0, 1 or more successor tasks (Listed in Arraylist as ID of task).

I'd like to code this in Kotlin first and once I fully understand it, I'd then like to move to Scala to compare performance.

Comment: That;s a very specific request, and sounds like the "Please write my code" questions so it might get closed. However, presumably you have an algorithm in mind - can't you write the code? It seems you do know both languages in order to want to performance-test between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translated to Kotlin and slightly refactored [this Java implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9774655/13968673):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // The example dependency graph
    val end = Task("End", 0)
    val F = Task("F", 2, end)
    val A = Task("A", 3, end)
    val X = Task("X", 4, F, A)
    val Q = Task("Q", 2, A, X)
    val start = Task("Start", 0, Q)
    val allTasks = hashSetOf(end, F, A, X, Q, start)

    calculateCriticalPath(allTasks)
    prettyPrintResult(allTasks)
}

fun calculateCriticalPath(tasks: Collection<Task>) {
    // tasks whose critical cost has been calculated
    val completed = hashSetOf<Task>()
    // tasks whose critical cost needs to be calculated
    val remaining = tasks.toHashSet()

    // Backflow algorithm
    // while there are tasks whose critical cost isn't calculated.
    while (remaining.isNotEmpty()) {
        var progress = false

        // find a new task to calculate
        val it = remaining.iterator()
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            val task = it.next()
            if (completed.containsAll(task.dependencies)) {
                // all dependencies calculated, critical cost is max dependency critical cost, plus our cost
                val critical = task.dependencies.map { it.criticalCost }.maxOrNull() ?: 0
                task.criticalCost = critical + task.cost
                // set task as calculated an remove
                completed.add(task)
                it.remove()
                // note we are making progress
                progress = true
            }
        }
        // If we haven't made any progress then a cycle must exist in
        // the graph and we wont be able to calculate the critical path
        if (!progress) throw RuntimeException("Cyclic dependency, algorithm stopped!")
    }

    // get the cost
    val maxCost = tasks.map { it.criticalCost }.maxOrNull() ?: -1
    println("Critical path length (cost): $maxCost")

    calculateLatest(tasks, maxCost)
    calculateEarly(tasks)
}

fun calculateLatest(tasks: Collection<Task>, maxCost: Int) = tasks.forEach { it.setLatest(maxCost) }

fun calculateEarly(tasks: Collection<Task>) = initials(tasks).forEach {
    it.earlyStart = 0
    it.earlyFinish = it.cost
    it.setEarlyForDependencies()
}

fun initials(tasks: Collection<Task>): Collection<Task> {
    val dependencies = tasks.flatMap { it.dependencies }.toSet()
    return tasks.filter { it !in dependencies }.also {
        println("Initial nodes: ${it.joinToString { node -> node.name }}\n")
    }
}

fun prettyPrintResult(tasks: Collection<Task>) {
    val format = "%1$-10s %2$-5s %3$-5s %4$-5s %5$-5s %6$-5s %7$-10s\n"
    System.out.format(format, "Task", "ES", "EF", "LS", "LF", "Slack", "Critical?")
    tasks.sortedWith { o1, o2 -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name) }.forEach {
        System.out.format(
            format, it.name, it.earlyStart, it.earlyFinish, it.latestStart, it.latestFinish,
            it.latestStart - it.earlyStart, if (it.isCritical()) "Yes" else "No"
        )
    }
}

// A wrapper class to hold the tasks during the calculation
class Task(
    var name: String, // a name for the task for printing
    var cost: Int, // the actual cost of the task
    vararg dependencies: Task
) {
    // the cost of the task along the critical path
    var criticalCost = 0

    // the earliest start
    var earlyStart = 0

    // the earliest finish
    var earlyFinish = -1

    // the latest start
    var latestStart = 0

    // the latest finish
    var latestFinish = 0

    // the tasks on which this task is dependant
    var dependencies = hashSetOf(*dependencies)

    fun setLatest(maxCost: Int) {
        latestStart = maxCost - criticalCost
        latestFinish = latestStart + cost
    }

    fun setEarlyForDependencies() {
        val completionTime = earlyFinish
        dependencies.forEach {
            if (completionTime >= it.earlyStart) {
                it.earlyStart = completionTime
                it.earlyFinish = completionTime + it.cost
            }
            it.setEarlyForDependencies()
        }
    }

    fun isCritical() = earlyStart == latestStart

    fun isDependent(t: Task): Boolean = dependencies.contains(t) || dependencies.any { it.isDependent(t) }
}
```